# Enabling and disabling components via select checkbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have component and I'm trying disable panelGrid below.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxId" value="#{bean.checked}">
    <p:ajax update="panelId" event="click"/>                                    
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:panelGrid id="panelId" rendered="#{!bean.checked}">
    <h:outputLabel>some text</h:outputLabel>
    <h:outputLabel>#registrationBB.registrationModel.homeAddress.actualAddressMathWithRegistration}</h:outputLabel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

As a result the clicking on checkbox doesn't take no effect. The check indicator doesn't even appear on checkbox component and value bean:checked doesn't sent to the server.
I tried to use  also. Check indicator appeared but the panel is not refreshed

How to use update via checkbox right?

Comment: A shoot in the dark: try `<f:ajax event="click" render="panelId" />` instead. There are some specific conditions wherein `<p:ajax>` don't work and I believe one of them is being wrapped in a non-PrimeFaces component.

Comment: Do you have a `h:form` wrapping around all these?

Comment: Yes, the form is present

Comment: @BalusC If I try to use event="click" the check indicator doesn't appear in both cases

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example below is what I got to work:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkboxId" value="#{indexBean.checked}" >
        <p:ajax event="change" update="panelId" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:panelGrid id="panelId" style="border:solid 1px black;" >
        <h:outputLabel rendered="#{!indexBean.checked}" >some text</h:outputLabel>
        <h:outputText rendered="#{!indexBean.checked}" value="some text 2" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I had to change the `<p:ajax>` event from click to change to get the checkbox working. The other issue is if you don't render the `<h:panelGrid>` the id can not be found to update, so you want to move the rendered attribute to the components inside your `<h:panelGrid>` but still update the `<h:panelGrid>`.

Comment: What version of Primefaces are you using? This doesn't work in version 4, the panelGrid is unaffected no matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: @Nab Probably version 3.x something. This question was asked years before 4.0 was released.

Comment: I had similar issues with a custom jsf component in 5.0, I solved it by wrapping it in a panel and updating the panel instead. Could try that.

Comment: @MarkRobinson This was the catch
The other issue is if you don't render the `<h:panelGrid>` the id can not be found to update, so you want to move the rendered attribute to the components inside your `<h:panelGrid>`

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation. Your backing bean field doesn't have to be a boolean. If you had a backing bean with fields:

```
private List<SelectItem> myStringList;
private String myString;
```

then you initialize myStringList like this before the form load:

```
myStringList = Arrays.asList(new SelectItem("one", "The Number One"),
                new SelectItem("two", "The number two")
        );
```

then you could do this:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneRadio id="ctlSearchType" value="#{mybean.myString}"  layout="grid" columns="3">
       <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.myStringList}" />
       <p:ajax event="change" update="ctlone,ctltwo"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:panelGrid id="panelId" style="border:solid 1px black;" >
       <p:outputLabel for="ctlone" value="Field one:"/>
       <p:inputText value="#{mybean.whatever}" id="ctlone" size="8" maxlength="10" disabled="#{mybean.myString eq 'one'}"/>
       <p:outputLabel for="ctltwo" value="Field two:"/>
       <p:inputText value="#{mybean.whatevertwo}" id="ctltwo" size="8" maxlength="10" disabled="#{mybean.myString eq 'two'}"/>                         
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Using 'SelectItem' is sort of not very common anymore since normal lists are supported too and a selectOneRadio is something totally different than a selectBooleanCheckbox.